# Is the following date stamp at the bottom of a series of emails valid?

Tags: email

My boss supposedly received an email, as well as a follow-up, complaining about my work. The content leads me to believe it is actually a setup. The 2nd email from the client has my bosses reply at the bottom with a date stamp without a time and looks like this:

On 4/7/17, Tony Smith tonys@ultra.co.za wrote:

> Dear Mr Jones
>
> Noted. Thanks.
>
> Regards

Every other email I have ever seen has a time, as well as a date.
Is the time, without date, in the example given authentic?

Answer (score 1):

Anything in an email can be forged, including the sender, receiver, delivery or origin time, the quoted text, any times and/or dates, and so on. In truth, there's a lot of clients that use "On X, Y wrote:", where X may be a date, a date time, or whatever else a developer feels like putting there, and Y is usually the name and email, or sometimes just the name or email, of the original sender as written. There is absolutely **no** requirement anywhere that says it must include the date, time, and sender; it's just a common implementation. I've also seen "Y wrote:" variety of quotation as well.

Some clients hide this text by default but include it with the response, other clients have to be told to include quotations by default. Regardless, if someone wanted to alter it, they usually can; it's basically plain/rich text that can be edited like any other part of the email. I don't know of any clients that prohibit editing this part of the email.

So, it's really not even a matter of forgery. Someone could literally just have clicked on the date and edited it using a normal keyboard, no hacking skills required. Or it could have been more deliberately crafted by someone skilled in the art of writing emails by protocol (e.g. telnet into a server and send raw data commands). Or just formatted some text so it looks like a quote. You have no way of knowing short of finding the original email buried in some log somewhere.

If you find it suspect, you can simply assume that it is *possible* to have been edited before sending. It requires next to no effort to fake date/time/text in an email, especially if you claim to be quoting someone else. You can either not worry about it, or if it comes down to it, you can challenge it; if it gets as far as being a legal matter, most courts in most jurisdictions can subpoena email log records, which in many cases have to be retained for at least a few years, depending on your jurisdiction.